# how set report path in pytest?

Tags: python, pytest, pytest-html

Good morning, I have a question about report html - pytest.

In my test I have 4 files and 3.4 tests in each file. I would like to create a report for each file that will be in a different folder, e.g.
for file1 - folder1 etc.
And start my test:

```
pytest -s test*.py --html=$REPORT/tests/report.html
```

However, everything gets in one file and one folder. how can this be changed?
variable in code:
`repoPa = os.getenv("report")`

Comment: The HTML report is written for a test run, so you can run each test in a separate call, e.g. smth like `find . -name "test_*.py" -exec "pytest {} --html=report_{}.html" \;` etc.

Comment: Yes, I know, but I need only one run all test and its my problem

Comment: Then you will need to write a custom plugin for that, as `pytest-html` doesn't write reports per test item. Take a look at the [`HTMLReport`](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest-html/blob/1abfe5d590fc5938daf545288288466b3262279d/pytest_html/plugin.py#L101) class, esp. the [`_generate_report`](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest-html/blob/1abfe5d590fc5938daf545288288466b3262279d/pytest_html/plugin.py#L340) method and implement custom version that writes one report file per test item.